# OrientDB Wrong search result

Tags: orientdb

Seem that OrientDB doesn't return the correct result for the simple search.

I created a class node `item` with 2 properties `id` and `flag`

- `id`: type STRING, index: UNIQUE
- `flag`: type DECIMAL

`flag` can be set by `1`, `0`, or `null` value.


I use the query below to get all `item` which has `flag` is `1`

```
`select from item where flag = 1`
```

But the query returns nothing.

**Note:** I have tested on `2.2.7` and `2.2.10`, and seem that this issue only occurs if `flag` was defined in schema before feeding data.
Is it bug?

[image]
**UPDATED**:  Added sample database. [Get it here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9uJbevAJq9UjZRMWRKMkYwWE0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `select from item where 1 = flag` it works.

For your query `select from item where flag = 1` could you open an issue on github attaching your database ?

Comment: Thanks so much! It works like a charm. I will open an issue on github soon.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on 2.2.10, no problems here:

```
create class item extends v
create property item.id STRING
create property item.flag DECIMAL
insert into item(id,flag) values ("id1",1)
select from item where flag = 1
```

Also added `UNIQUE` index on `id` from studio -> schema.

Output:
[image: Select ID OrientDB]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your quickly answer. But seem that your data too small to reproduce this issue. Please my attached data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9uJbevAJq9UjZRMWRKMkYwWE0)